# Simple VBA selection code error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple VBA code with which I want to change the background of the selected cells. Somehow the command Selection. that I learned before doesn't work. Could you help me with this code? I know the answer is probably stupid, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
    Sub set_background_color()

       'Add background color to selected cells
       Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End Sub
```

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry for the vague question, it's my first question on stack overflow so I didn't think of the importance of the type of error. It gives me the error "Compile error: Expected function or variable".

It is attached to a button, but even if I run it as a macro without button it gives me the same error.

EDIT 2: I'm running Excel 2011 on a Mac, until now it never gave me any compatibility issues in VBA. However this does not seem to work.

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error or what?

Comment: What is selected when you run this code? How do you call it? Is this attached to a button?

Comment: It may not be enough to set the interior color to red. You need to control the type (solid), transparency, and visibility as well. A cell could be red and transparent - in which case you can't see anything was done...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not within your code, it is within your cells.

Check the **locked** status of the cells and the **protection** status of the worksheet.

Comment: I wonder how do you know it's a problem with the `Protection` The question doesn't give any such indication... Or am I missing something? :)

Comment: I copied the code and tested it.  It worked.  I ask my self -> How could I deliberately create a failure?  The only thing I thought of was to protect some cells.  Your comment got me thinking that if a Shape or a Chart was selected instead of a Range, we also could make it fail.......what else could it be???

Comment: It is interesting that it worked for you. I suppose you tried it on a PC. Might it be that it has to do with using a Mac? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your worksheet is not protected then try this

```
Sub set_background_color()
    Dim r As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Selection
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Selection"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yup we can use `TypeName(Selection)` as well :)